# ¿Como levantar un hilo cuando cae?

Tags: c#, hilos

Tengo un hilo que controla otro hilo, el problema es que necesito que el otro hilo se reinicie cada x tiempo y al intentar iniciarlo de nuevo no puedo hacer que se inicie.

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException:'Subproceso en ejecución o terminado;no se puede reiniciar.'

¿Hay alguna forma de reutilizar/reiniciar el hilo?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadStart consola = new ThreadStart(controladorHilos);
        Thread thread = new Thread(consola);

        thread.Start();

    }
```

Aqui es donde **se crea el subproceso**, donde me da el error. Me pasa tanto poniendo el hilo como `proceso` como poniéndolo con `subproceso`. 
La cosa es que más adelante necesitare que el hilo controle más cosas.

```
   public static void controladorHilos()
    {
        ThreadStart consola = new ThreadStart(hilo);
        Thread hconsola = new Thread(consola);
        log("se lanza el hilo");

            hconsola.Start()


    }
```

Según el ciclo de vida de  los hilos, una vez el hilo termina, no hay manera de levantarlo, ¿Hay alguna alternativa a esto? ¿Alguna forma de que el hilo aborte, pare, termine, y después se levante? **No vale que el hilo quede en pausa, tiene que empezar todo de 0**

El método hilo:
El metodo hilo abre un socket a una dirección ip, vía telnet, lanza varios comandos y empieza a recibir información del socket. Lo que pasa es que la sesión abierta en el socket caduca cada X tiempo o pierde conexión cada X tiempo, el socket no me envía ningún mensaje de que se haya perdido la conexión por lo que hilo sigue escuchando al socket, aunque no haya conexión. El socket se abre a otra sede ajena, por lo que no se me ocurre ninguna manera mejor de solucionarlo.

```
public static void hilo(){
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
    String data = null;
    TcpClient cliente = new TcpClient();
    while (true)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = cliente.GetStream();
        int i;

        while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
            Console.WriteLine("Recibido: {0}", data);

            data = data.ToUpper();

            byte[] msg;

            if (data.Contains("login")){

            console.write("login username password");
            //Se abre buffer de datos y empiezo a recibir datos
            }

            if (data.Contains("Cualquier mensaje recibido del socket"))  
            {
                msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("queueinfo" + Environment.NewLine);
                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                //Aqui hay inserciones a una BBDD etc. Todo funciona ok.
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Tengo que aclarar que en el método hilo no se produce ningún error, el error viene del socket al que este hilo apunta, al perderse la conexión con el mismo, siempre pasa cada X tiempo, por lo que, necesito reiniciar todo esto y no sé exactamente como podría hacerlo.

Comment: Un disparo al aire, pero me parece que el hilo no está teniendo tiempo para iniciarse ya que el `while(true)` bloquea el hilo principal y se ejecuta muy rápido. Puedes hacer una prueba rápida y meter un `Thread.Sleep(1000)` al final (pero dentro) del while a ver si dándole un poco de tiempo el hilo ha podido iniciarse? P.D. Te recomendaría otro hilo en lugar del `while(true)` en el hilo principal, tal vez un `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: No tengo ni idea de como funciona el `BackgroundWorker`, pero de todas formas le echaré un ojo a ver si veo documentación sobre el tema, es el primer "servicio" que programo y estoy un poco perdido.

Comment: Si, la he visto, pero me parece que es posible que al hilo no le haya dado tiempo a "nacer" del todo y el `IsAlive` todavía siga siendo `false` por lo que entra otra vez. Podrías incluso meter un mensaje por consola simplemente para monitorizar cuantas veces pasa por ahí. Es posible que no sea ese el problema pero mejor si lo descartamos. Si se confirman mis sospechas te intento explicar mejor el por que pasa esto.

Comment: probablemente tengas razón, creo que ya entiendo lo que dices. La proxima vez que esté en el ordenador donde tengo el programa lo miro, he dejado el programa en ejecucion hasta mañana, a ver si se registran los fallos en el log. 
Pero es eso, supongo que al ser while(true) no hay tiempo de espera entre cada vuelta en el bucle por lo que lo ejecuta más de una vez y da error. De todas formas, no me ha vuelto a dar ni un fallo, llevaba un par de horas intentando provocarlo sacando el cable de red etc.

Comment: Coméntanos con lo que sea para que intentemos ayudarte ;)

Comment: Pensaba que sí, pero no consigo que el hilo se reinicie. Edito para poner lo que me dice.

Comment: Sería útil entender el cuadro mas completo, o sea, entender qué hace tu método `hilo`. Porque cuando veo `Thread.abort()`, en seguida eso indica un problema de diseño. en todo caso, la respuesta es no, no se puede reiniciar un hilo que ya corrió y terminó.  Una alternativa es simplemente creando un hilo nuevo a cada iteración: `new Thread(...)`. Pero la verdad es que estoy convencido que hay una mejor forma de hacerlo, pero tienes que incluir un [mcve].

Comment: El metodo hilo abre un socket a una dirección ip, vía telnet, lanza varios comandos y empieza a recibir información del socket. Lo que pasa es que la sesión abierta en el socket caduca cada X tiempo o pierde conexión cada X tiempo, el socket no me envía ningún mensaje de que se haya perdido la conexión por lo que hilo sigue escuchando al socket, aunque no haya conexión. El socket se abre a otra sede ajena, por lo que no se me ocurre ninguna manera mejor de solucionarlo.

Comment: Uy! Ha cambiado el cuento desde mi último comentario. El problema que tienes ahora (al contrario que en el otro código que nos enseñaste) es que el hilo se inicia, se muere (no haría falta el abort, debería de morir el solito) y luego lo quieres lanzar otra vez. Eso no se puede/debe hacer. Tienes que hacer que el hilo no muera (ejecución contínua) o volver a crear un hilo nuevo cada vez (lo que me parece un overkill). Para evitar más ediciones y demás, podrías ponernos en el código una representación lo más real posible de tu flujo de hilos actual?

Comment: Creo que con lo que ya he puesto, adjuntando algo parecido a la clase hilo se puede ver lo que pasa. La única diferencia está en los registros a la BBDD contraseñas y demás que no he puesto, tal vez alguna variable sin inicializar que he dejado por ahí, pero vamos, el hilo no falla en ningún punto.

Comment: Por confirmar: `controladorHilos` realmente hace eso que indicas? Inicia un hilo (`Start`), pone a dormir el hilo que le invoca (`Thread.Sleep`) y luego fuerza un aborto del hilo (`abort`) dentro de un `while(true)`? O eso sigue siendo código de ejemplo que no encaja con tu código actual?

Comment: Ahora mismo es lo que tengo en mi programa, pero es lo último que he hecho por probar, simplemente podría quitar el abort y demás, dejando ``controladorHilos`` con únicamente ``start`` de los hilos que en un futuro vaya a poner, por ahora solo está esto. **Edito de nuevo para que quede constancia de que eso ya no lo utilizaré, al ver que es algo que no tiene sentido** mientras que busco alguna solución para relanzar todo el programa.

Comment: De todas formas, estoy empezando a pensar que lo que mi jefe me ha pedido no es viable, simplemente creo que lo acabaré solucionando con el programador de tareas de windows o algo...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67961/discussion-between-aritz-bello-and-frikinside).

Comment: Yo creo que lo que necesitas hacer es jugar con el timeout del TcpClient para que no se tranque. Luego puedes manejar la excepción de forma normal y reinicializar el TcpClient de ser necesario, pero sin necesidad de jugar con los hilos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final resolví el problema con lo siguiente, que, realmente era esto lo que buscaba.

```
public static void main(){
    while(true){
        //Creamos el objeto en cada vuelta del bucle
        ThreadStart consola = new ThreadStart(metodo_convertido_en_hilo);
        Thread thread = new Thread(consola);

        thread.Start();
        thread.sleep(1000*60*60); //Para que el hilo se relance cada hora.
        thread.Abort();
    }
 }
```

Con esto lo que consigo es basicamente reutilizar el mismo hilo una y otra vez, así, en caso de que los buffers del hilo se queden pillados, los "reinstancio", consiguiendo así la mayor relacion entre menor redundancia/menor perdida de datos.

Gracias a la persona que estuvo en el chat conmigo, gracias a ello se me ocurrió la solución.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, cada iteración creas un hilo nuevo, no reinicias el que ya tienes, con lo cual estás creando 24 hilos al día. Depende lo que hagan los hilos, se te van a ir creando y añadiendo cada vez más hilos, de no ser que mueran antes de crear uno nuveo

Comment: Tiene razón, de hecho, se me ha olvidado añadirlo, pero después del sleep hay un thread.Abort();

Answer (score 3):

Yo cambiaría el enfoque a TAP [(patrón asíncrono basado en tareas)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) a efectos de tener una lógica más simplificada. Esto implica usar el espacio de nombres [`System.Threading.Tasks`](http://respagblog.azurewebsites.net/programacion-asincronica-en-net/) y los operadores `async` y `await`:

Te dejo un ejemplo (compílalo en tu computadora ya que en web no se lanza bien) aquí: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1RjQjM

Empezamos por cambiar `hilo`:

```
private static void hilo()
{
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
    String data = null;
    TcpClient cliente = new TcpClient();
    NetworkStream stream = cliente.GetStream();
    int i;

    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Nótese que en caso de no querer retornar ningún valor podemos usar `void` o `Task` mientras que para devolver un resultado usamos `Task<int>` para un `int`, por ejemplo.
Otra cosa: eliminé el `while (true)`.

A continuación, cambiar el "Controlador de hilos":

```
// Nota: "async" indica que puede esperar el resultado de una tarea asíncrona
private static async void controladorHilos()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            // Aquí "esperamos" a que se complete el hilo.
            await Task.Run(() => Clase.hilo());

            // Este hilo en específico se detendrá a esperar la llamada.
            // Si todo sale bien, lo ejecutará de nuevo y esperará una y otra vez.
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Si ocurre un error en el hilo lo capturamos aquí.
            Console.Write("Excepción: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Y lo invocamos desde el método `Main`:

```
// Aquí no esperaremos, por lo tanto no necesitamos "async".
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Iniciamos la tarea y nos despreocupamos sin "esperar" (await) el resultado
    Task.Run(() => controladorHilos());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Creo que el problema es que `hilo` no lanza error, sino que se tranca de forma silenciosa.

Comment: Lo que yo entiendo es que el hilo muere y no tiene manera de saberlo y relanzarlo. Para demostrar mi código, cree el siguiente Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1RjQjM (hay que compilarlo uno mismo ya que no funciona muy bien en web). Espero que sirva!

Comment: ah.. es que con su última edición se entiende diferentemente lo que está haciendo. Qué se va a hacer...